# Funny Error initialiazing a class variable with expression

Tags: php, oop

Why is this giving error?

```
class content {
    protected $id,$title,$content,$image,$imagedirectory,$page;
    protected $sid = md5(time()); //In this line : parse error, expecting `','' or `';''
}
```

Comment: ROFLMAO! "expecting"… That's what *she* said………… XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`md5(time())` is an expression.

Field initializations are not allowed to use expressions, only literals.

Instead, you could do:

```
class content {
    protected $id, $title, $content, $image, $imagedirectory, $page, $sid;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sid = md5(time());
    }
}
```

Comment: +5 votes, but no one noticed the error in his answer. 2 ` =  = ` in your function. Anyways I will fix it.